# What is the SQL query in Access to replace all column values with one of it's values, which depends on values of other attributes?

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010

Suppose I have the following table T:

```
A | B | C
--+---+--
aa| ba| 1
ab| bb| 2
ac| bc| 3
```

What would be an SQL query to get the following:

```
A | B | C
--+---+--
aa| ba| 2
ab| bb| 2
ac| bc| 2
```

To clarify I would expect something like:

```
SELECT *
FROM T
WHERE /* specify to replace all entries of column C 
       with the value of C that corresponds to tuple
       where A="ab" AND B="bb" */
```

Comment: You can use the same table more than once in a query if you use aliases. - Or you can use a nested query on the same table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT t1.A, t1.B, t2.C
FROM T t1, T t2
WHERE t2.A="ab" AND t2.B="bb"
```